# How to group an Option group in html select from WordPress values?

Tags: php, wordpress, select, optgroup

I have this HTML optgroup select box that is populated from values stored in a WordPress database.

```
$field_val = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

echo '<select id="'.$field['id'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $key => $value) {
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($value);
    $bgtypes = $custom_fields['bgtype'];
    foreach($bgtypes as $bgkey => $type){

        echo '<optgroup label="'.$type.'">';
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.selected($value, $field_val, false).'>'.$key.'</option>';
        echo '</optgroup>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

It retrieves all the correct data however when it prints out the values the values are not "grouped".

Here is an example of the returned results:

```
<select id="_wpbp_background" name="_wpbp_background">
  <optgroup label="youtube">
  <option value="2777" >YouTube Playlist video</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="videos">
  <option value="2775" >Another Self Hosted Video</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="images">
  <option value="2774" >Image Slideshow Main</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="pattern">
  <option value="2773" >Carbon Pattern BG</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="solid">
  <option value="2772" >Purple Solid BG Color</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="audio">
  <option value="2771" >Test Audio File 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="images">
  <option value="2759" >test image slideshow</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="videos">
  <option value="2747"  selected='selected'>Test Hosted Video</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="youtube">
  <option value="2736" >YouTube Video 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="pattern">
  <option value="2718" >Pattern 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="videos">
  <option value="2711" >test video 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="audio">
  <option value="2693" >Test audio file 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="images">
  <option value="2670" >test image</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="solid">
  <option value="2669" >Blue Solid Background</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="solid">
  <option value="2667" >Red Background</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

If you look at the returned results you will notice that there are many groups with the same name. "Images" for example.

Is there a way I can modify the original PHP code to group those options like so:

```
<select id="_wpbp_background" name="_wpbp_background">
  <optgroup label="images">
  <option value="2774" >Image Slideshow Main</option>
  <option value="2759" >test image slideshow</option>
  <option value="2670" >test image</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="solid">
  <option value="2669" >Blue Solid Background</option>
  <option value="2667" >Red Background</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

======================================================================
**EDIT:**

Here is the original function that I call to get the "backgrounds" custom post type elements:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of backgrounds
 */
function get_backgrounds(){
    $bgs = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'   => $this->cpt,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'     => 'title',
    ));
    $backgrounds = array();
    $backgrounds[__('-- Select Background --', $this->prefix)] = '';
    foreach($bgs as $key => $value){
        $backgrounds[$value->post_title] = $value->ID;
    }
    return $backgrounds;
}
```

When called the above code displays

```
Array
(
    [-- Select Background --] => 
    [YouTube Video 1] => 2736
    [YouTube Playlist video] => 2777
    [test video 1] => 2711
    [test image slideshow] => 2759
    [test image] => 2670
    [Test Hosted Video] => 2747
    [Test Audio File 2] => 2771
    [Test audio file 1] => 2693
    [Red Background] => 2667
    [Purple Solid BG Color] => 2772
    [Pattern 1] => 2718
    [Image Slideshow Main] => 2774
    [Carbon Pattern BG] => 2773
    [Blue Solid Background] => 2669
    [Another Self Hosted Video] => 2775
)
```

**First code block that partially works:**

```
// <optgroup> of the previous <option>
$previous = "";

// variable to set the first group
$first_group = true;

foreach ($field['options'] as $key => $value) {
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($value);

    if (isset($custom_fields['bgtype'][0]) && $custom_fields['bgtype'][0]) {
        $bgtypes = $custom_fields['bgtype'];

        foreach($bgtypes as $typebg){

            if ($typebg != $previous) {
                if (!$first_group) {
                    echo '</optgroup>';
                } else {
                    $first_group = false;
                }
                echo '<optgroup label="'.$typebg.'">';
                $previous = $typebg;
            }

            echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.selected($value, $field_val, false).'>'.$key.'</option>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</optgroup>';  // close last optgroup
echo '</select>';
```

The results of the first code block:

```
<select id="_wpbp_background" name="_wpbp_background">
  <optgroup label="youtube">
  <option value="2736" >YouTube Video 1</option>
  <option value="2777" >YouTube Playlist video</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="videos">
  <option value="2711" >test video 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="images">
  <option value="2759" >test image slideshow</option>
  <option value="2670" >test image</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="videos">
  <option value="2747"  selected='selected'>Test Hosted Video</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="audio">
  <option value="2771" >Test Audio File 2</option>
  <option value="2693" >Test audio file 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="solid">
  <option value="2667" >Red Background</option>
  <option value="2772" >Purple Solid BG Color</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="pattern">
  <option value="2718" >Pattern 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="images">
  <option value="2774" >Image Slideshow Main</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="pattern">
  <option value="2773" >Carbon Pattern BG</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="solid">
  <option value="2669" >Blue Solid Background</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="videos">
  <option value="2775" >Another Self Hosted Video</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

As you can see this code block partially groups the elements by their "bytpe". It groups some of them but NOT ALL. The way I got it to group this way was to add the `'orderby' => 'title'` to the initial function to display the backgrounds.

```
**Second code block:**
echo '<select id="'.$field['id'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $key => $value) {
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($value);

        $bgtypes = $custom_fields['bgtype'];

        foreach($bgtypes as $bgkey => $type){

            if(strpos($type,'images') !== false):

                $images.= '<optgroup label="'.$type.'">'.'<option value="'.$value.'" '.selected($value, $field_val, false).'>'.$key.'</option>'.'</optgroup>';
            elseif(strpos($type,'youtube') !== false):
                $youtube.= '<optgroup label="'.$type.'">'.'<option value="'.$value.'" '.selected($value, $field_val, false).'>'.$key.'</option>'.'</optgroup>';

            else:
                $other.= '<optgroup label="'.$type.'">'.'<option value="'.$value.'" '.selected($value, $field_val, false).'>'.$key.'</option>'.'</optgroup>';

            endif;

        }
}
echo $images;
echo $youtube;
echo $other;
echo '</select>';
```

On this code I changed the strpos function to `if(strpos($type,'images') !== false):` to compare against the actual "bgtype" as the $bgkey variable was returning 0 for all results.

Unfortunately this code still returns the list not grouped by their "bgtypes".

**Edit 3: New Code that returns "PostId", "Post Title" & "BGType".**

```
// Get a list of all the created backgrounds
$bgs = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'wpbp-backgrounds',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby'     => 'title',
));

foreach($bgs as $key => $value){
    // Post Id
    $cpid =  $value->ID;
    // Post Title
    $cptitle = $value->post_title;
    // BGType
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($cpid);
    $cpbgtype = $custom_fields['bgtype'];

    if (isset($custom_fields['bgtype'][0]) && $custom_fields['bgtype'][0]) {
        //This is where I would create all the code and group them
    }
}
```

The results of the above code using `echo $cpid . ' - ' . $cptitle .' - '.$cpbgtype.'<br>';` are:

```
2736 - YouTube Video 1 - youtube
2777 - YouTube Playlist video - youtube
2711 - test video 1 - videos
2759 - test image slideshow - images
2670 - test image - images
2747 - Test Hosted Video - videos
2771 - Test Audio File 2 - audio
2693 - Test audio file 1 - audio
2667 - Red Background - solid
2772 - Purple Solid BG Color - solid
2718 - Pattern 1 - pattern
2774 - Image Slideshow Main - images
2773 - Carbon Pattern BG - pattern
2669 - Blue Solid Background - solid
2775 - Another Self Hosted Video - videos
```

This above code seems to provide all the details for the items. I am just not sure how to group them into optgroup and display them ordered in the dropdown.

**Edit 4: Output of var_dump()**
If I run this code: `var_dump($cpbgtype);` I receive this output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "youtube"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "youtube"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "videos"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "images"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "images"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "videos"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "audio"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "audio"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "solid"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "solid"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "pattern"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "images"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "pattern"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "solid"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "videos"
}
```

However if I run this code `var_dump($custom_fields['bgtype'][0]);` I receive this output. Not sure which one to call as this one is actually how I can refer to each "bgtype"

```
string(7) "youtube"
string(7) "youtube"
string(6) "videos"
string(6) "images"
string(6) "images"
string(6) "videos"
string(5) "audio"
string(5) "audio"
string(5) "solid"
string(5) "solid"
string(7) "pattern"
string(6) "images"
string(7) "pattern"
string(5) "solid"
string(6) "videos"
```

**Edit 5: Output of var_dump($custom_fields)**

```
array(14) {
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1421540192:1"
  }
  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["bgtype"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "youtube"
  }
  ["poster"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(70) "http://localhost/wordpress-dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mash_ups.png"
  }
  ["volume"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  ["mute"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  ["showplay"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  ["showmute"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  ["paused"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
  ["loopvideo"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
  ["ytbtnbg"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "#565656"
  }
  ["ytbtntxt"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "#ffffff"
  }
  ["video_controls"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "bottom_left"
  }
  ["playlist"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(59) "ZKa8OEPCZrg,goKm9Oafs3E,OCHy1nUdfu8,mpCFLr0NPjA,i3WX-VeNKmk"
  }
}
```

From this var_dump() I am after the BGType which in this case is:

```
["bgtype"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "youtube"
      }
```

This is whats returned for each individual background I call when in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a simple if test to see what the $key contains...

```
$field_val = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

            $bgtypes= array('youtube', 'videos', 'images', 'solid', 'audio'); // adjust this to create the headings. As far as i can see this will be more or less consistant? 

    foreach($bgtypes as $bgkey):

        //remove plurals to make checking easier

        if (substr($bgkey, -1) == 's')
            $bgkey = substr($bgkey, 0, -1);

        foreach($field['options'] as $option => $key):  
            if(stripos($option, $bgkey) !==false ):
                $options[$bgkey][$option]= $key;
                unset($field['options'][$option]);
            endif;
        endforeach;  

    endforeach;

    $options['other']= $field['options'];


    echo '<select id="'.$field['id'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'">';


        foreach($options as $item=>$key):
            echo '<optgroup label="'.$item.'">';
                foreach($key as $line=>$data):
                    echo '<option value="'.$data.'" >'.$line.'</option>';
                endforeach;
            echo '</optgroup>';
        endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
```

i had to guess as to the output of some of the arrays but it should be close enough.

Answer to 3rd edit:

```
        $bgs = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'   => 'wpbp-backgrounds',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'     => 'title',
    ));

    foreach($bgs as $key => $value){
        // Post Id
        $cpid =  $value->ID;
        // Post Title
        $cptitle = $value->post_title;
        // BGType
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom($cpid);
        $cpbgtype = $custom_fields['bgtype'][0];

        // since the data is associated with the post its easier to implement.
        if (isset($custom_fields['bgtype'][0]) && $custom_fields['bgtype'][0]) {
            $output[$cpbgtype][]= '<option value="'.$cpid.'" >'.$cptitle.'</option>'  ;
        }
    }

    echo '<select id="'.$field['id'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'">'; // dont know if the $field values are still there

    foreach($output as $type=>$data):
        echo '<optgroup label="'.$type.'">';
            foreach($data as $item):
                echo $item;
            endforeach; 
        echo '</optgroup>';
    endforeach;

    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks @David, I tried your code however it still doesn't group the "bgtypes".

Comment: yes modify it as you see fit......if this is the grouping element `<optgroup label="images">`, i've adjusted the above, but you will need to check the compare values yourself...

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for the help. No matter what I try I still can't get your code to group the options. Could it be because in the first foreach loop I am looping through all the "options" and the second (inner) foreach loop loops through the "bgtypes".

Comment: ok i think it should be comparing the correct key now if you check it. Basically the strpos function looks for the value within the variable, so if you look for 'image' and your key is images it will return 0 (which we accept as true) if the key is IMAGE, it will return false (its case sensitive). You need to decide what to group the elements together by: look at the code you entered above, what is it out putting? what value are you using to check etc. Just create a new else if loop for ea value you want to check and obvioiusly a new variable.

Comment: Hi @David, thanks again. I am trying to group the elements by their "bgtype" (images, youtube, video, pattern) ect. I will add to my above question to show you the two ways I am trying to get the code working.

Comment: i updated the code above, you have plurals mixed up with mixed cases in your keys. So remove the instances of plurals and check using stripos (case insensitive).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your patience, time and help. Your code is amazing and works. I just have one item which is the "Red Background" that falls under the "Other" background when it should fall under the "images" optgroup. I will look into this and try to figure out why this is happening. One again a huge thankyou.

Comment: I have still been tinkering to get it to work correctly. If I gave you the code to get the "PostId", "Post Title" & "BgType" from the beginning instead of assuming the BGType name would this make it easier. I have added to my above question showing you the initial code that gathers all the details. From there I just need to place them in a dropdown list grouped by their "BGTypes". There are only 6 BGTypes: 'audio', 'images', 'pattern', 'solid', 'videos', 'youtube'

Comment: yes you can post it but there has to be a link between the bgtype and the field. You can of course pull single items out and re-order them, but if you add new items to options it will need to contain the word you are using to describe.

Comment: Thanks @David, In regards to the lists, each item will not always contain the word used to describe the item type. Therefore I added the new code to the original question that will return the BGType for each item. Every new item or new post that is created will contain a "BGType" when it is created. Is it possible to modify your code to use the new code that I have provided? This way by using the "$cpbgtype" you will know exactly the "BGType" each item belongs to.

Comment: The items can only every be one of the 6 BGTypes. There is no "Other" type available for them.

Comment: Also to note, the names of the posts can be anything as well. I just named the initial posts that way so for in development mode I would know what "BGType" each post belonged to.

Comment: Hi @David, just wondering if you are able to please look at the new code I added to the question. Thank you

Comment: ok updated it again. Try and understand whats going on with the loops so you can modify it yourself. Btw see a note i left, im note sure if the variables used to name the select are still valid.

Comment: Thank you once again @David. I really appreciate your help. I know we are so close to nailing this. When I tried the new code I got the warning: "Warning: Illegal offset type in ..." It refers to the chunk of code: "$output[$cpbgtype][]= '<option value="'.$cpid.'" >'.$cptitle.'</option>'  ;" I am trying to understand each code you write. My issues are that because I grab the actual "backgrounds" and the "BGTypes" at the same time, I am not sure how to group (optgroup) them and display each item in that group.

Comment: the approach is to combine them into a assoc. array using foreach. But anyway before the line $output[$cpbgtype], var_dump($cpbgtype) and post back what it outputs.

Comment: Hi @David, have just updated the code displaying the output I receive from running to different var_dump() commands.

Comment: ok the problem is this is an array, is $custom_fields['bgtype'][0] the correct output for that post (i.e. each line is 1 post in the bgs category). I dont really see how you are getting a array of values back from $custom_fields['bgtype'], do you have multiple values saved for each post?

Comment: Yes I receive multiple values back for the BGType call. In the code I use "$bgs = get_posts" to get the array of the different backgrounds. I then loop through the individual backgrounds & place the details into the variables: "$cpid" & "$cptitle". I can only get the "BGTypes" once I am in the loop of reading the backgrounds. I get all the details related to each individual background using this code "$custom_fields = get_post_custom($cpid);". From the results of this call I try and place the "BGType" into a variable: $cpbgtype = $custom_fields['bgtype'];

Comment: ok try it now. Btw you might change the custom fields function to get_post_meta(); for the custom field. Its a bit cleaner.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much. You nailed it. It works perfectly. I need to do a lot more research on assoc array to understand them better.